# mootools 1.4.5 scroller functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mootools

I am using horizontal scrolling for my news on my website. I am making use of mootools scroller functionality for this. when I am using mootools 1.1 version , the scroller is working but it is conflicting with jQuery. I can use jQuery.noConflict(). But I have so many files in which I used jQuery and which are depending on each other. so I moved to mootools  1.4.5 core and 1.4.0.1 more. so now these mootools version don't have any conflicts with jQuery but the the scroller functionality is not working.
I just want to know is there any major change in terms of scroller functionality of mootools 1.1 and 1.4.5.?

Comment: Please can anyone answer this, it is urgent for me...

Comment: not that i know of ! I've also been using scroller utility class for a long time and never had problems... Maybe post a bit of script?